# Quotient module

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. If $P$ be a prime ideal of $R$ and $S=R-P$, why $S^{-1}(R\oplus R)\cong S^{-1}R\oplus S^{-1}R$?

Answer (score 6):

HINT:

Look at the map of $S^{-1}R$ modules
$$
S^{-1}R\oplus S^{-1}R\rightarrow S^{-1}(R\oplus R),\quad
\frac xs\oplus\frac yt\mapsto\frac{tx\oplus sy}{st}.
$$
It is surjective. Compute its kernel.

Answer (score 6):

More generally, if $S$ is any subset of $R$ and $M,N$ are $R$-modules, then $S^{-1} (M \oplus N) \cong S^{-1} M \oplus S^{-1} N$. This is simply because $S^{-1} (-)$ is left adjoint to the forgetful functor from $S^{-1} R$-modules to $R$-modules, hence preserves *all* colimits, in particular direct sums. But you can also check this directly. Beware that it will get rather cumbersome when you don't use any universal properties (one has to prove well-definedness of the maps etc.).

Alternatively, use that $S^{-1} M = M \otimes_R S^{-1} R$ and that the tensor product commutes with direct sums (in fact all colimits) in each variable (again since $\mathrm{Hom}$ provides a right adjoint).

Comment: Just to confirm: you're saying that for any $S^{-1}R$ - module $P$ we have $$\begin{eqnarray*} \mbox{Hom}(S^{-1}(M\oplus N),P) &\cong& \mbox{Hom}(M \oplus N,\text{Forget}(P) ) \\
 &\cong& \mbox{Hom}(M,\text{Forget}(P)) \oplus \mbox{Hom}(N,\text{Forget}(P))\\
 &\cong& \mbox{Hom}(S^{-1}M,P) \oplus \mbox{Hom}
(S^{-1}N,P)\\ &\cong& \mbox{Hom}(S^{-1}M \oplus S^{-1}N,P)\end{eqnarray*}$$
and so by Yoneda we have the isomorphism of the OP.

Comment: I'm not really saying that one should repeat the proofs of all these useful lemmas of category theory again and again in special cases. Just use them.